# Python Matlibplot DateFormat X Label Invisible

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to plot the following csv data.
The data is ticked at 1 minute interval:

```
# cat futures-sample.txt  | head
2019/05/16-09:15 27830 2031
2019/05/16-09:16 27815 995
2019/05/16-09:17 27829 961
2019/05/16-09:18 27848 663
2019/05/16-09:19 27873 869
2019/05/16-09:20 27847 854
2019/05/16-09:21 27828 784
2019/05/16-09:22 27813 676
2019/05/16-09:23 27828 700
2019/05/16-09:24 27849 665
```

I want the X-axis to be displayed at 1 hour interval.
For example:  9:00, 10:00, 11:00

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, DateFormatter

df = pd.read_csv('futures-sample.txt', names=['Time', 'HSIF', 'Volume'], delim_whitespace=True)

ax = df.set_index('Time').plot(y='HSIF')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M'))

fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig('/var/www/html/temp.png')
```

However, the graph does not show the X Label finally.
Do I miss something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `Time` column is a string, you can use `parse_dates=['Time']` in your `read_csv`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('futures-sample.txt', names=['Time', 'HSIF', 'Volume'],parse_dates=['Time'] ,delim_whitespace=True)
```